# Issue Parsing data from json in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

Hi I have a json file through which I am parsing data.
I can easily read the data i.e. name etc but can't able to read list inside that
eg reading data of appdetails and in appdetails reading other json

so far this is what I was doing and wanna make changes in the same because on the previous page click I am showing user the specific details on the basis of category he select .

````
```
class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final ProductModel item;
  const DetailScreen({Key? key, required this.item}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DetailScreen> createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}

class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body:  Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        height: 170,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                    child: Image.network(
                      '$iconLink${widget.item.logo}',
                      height: 107,
                      width: 107,
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
            
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```

```

class ProductModel {
  String? name;
  String? category;
  String? subcategory;
  String? imageUrl;
  String? logo;
  String? description;
  List<AppDetails>? appDetails;
  ProductModel(
      {this.name,
      this.category,
      this.subcategory,
      this.imageUrl,
      this.logo,
      this.description,
      this.appDetails});
  ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    category = json['category'];
    subcategory = json['subcategory'];
    imageUrl = json['imageUrl'];
    logo = json['logo'];
    description = json['description'];
    if (json['appDetails'] != null) {
      appDetails = <AppDetails>[];
      json['appDetails'].forEach((v) {
        appDetails!.add(AppDetails.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['name'] = name;
    data['category'] = category;
    data['subcategory'] = subcategory;
    data['imageUrl'] = imageUrl;
    data['logo'] = logo;
    data['description'] = description;
    if (appDetails != null) {
      data['appDetails'] = appDetails!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class AppDetails {
  String? systemOverview;
  List<Label>? multiDeviceSupport;
  List<Label>? mainFeatures;
  List<Label>? benefits;
  AppDetails(
      {this.systemOverview,
      this.multiDeviceSupport,
      this.mainFeatures,
      this.benefits});
  AppDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    systemOverview = json['systemOverview'];
    if (json['multiDeviceSupport'] != null) {
      multiDeviceSupport = <Label>[];
      json['multiDeviceSupport'].forEach((v) {
        multiDeviceSupport!.add(Label.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['mainFeatures'] != null) {
      mainFeatures = <Label>[];
      json['mainFeatures'].forEach((v) {
        mainFeatures!.add(Label.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['benefits'] != null) {
      benefits = <Label>[];
      json['benefits'].forEach((v) {
        benefits!.add(Label.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['systemOverview'] = systemOverview;
    if (multiDeviceSupport != null) {
      data['multiDeviceSupport'] =
          multiDeviceSupport!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (mainFeatures != null) {
      data['mainFeatures'] = mainFeatures!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (benefits != null) {
      data['benefits'] = benefits!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Label {
  String? label;
  Label({this.label});
  Label.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    label = json['label'];
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['label'] = label;
    return data;
  }
}

```

```

```
[{
    "name": "TestingApp",
    "category": "Production",
    "subcategory": "Productivity",
    "imageUrl": "Testing-Banner.jpg",
    "logo": "PI.png",
    "description": "Testing is an application for easy & effective Inspection",
    "appDetails": [{
            "systemOverview": "https:?????",
            "multiDeviceSupport": [{
                    "label": "Multi-Device"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Multi-Lingual"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Multi-Database"
                }
            ],
            "mainFeatures": [{
                    "label": "Testing"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Ease"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Select failure codes"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Add comments & take evidence Pictures"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Add comments & take evidence Pictures"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Search/view defects"
                }
            ],
            "benefits": [{
                    "label": "Easy & quick solution"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Go paperless"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Lower costs"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Improve quality"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Configurable on hand-held devices and tablets"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Electronic notifications to corresponding personnel’s"
                }

            ]
        }


    ]
}]
```
```
`
````

Answer (score 0):

```
        List appDetails = (json['appDetails'] as List?)?.map(
    (appdata)=>AppDetails(
                       systemOverview= appdata['systemOverview'],

                       multiDeviceSuppor=(appdata['multiDeviceSupport'] as List?)?.map(
(multiDeviceSupportdata)=>multiDeviceSupportdata['label']).toList,

                       mainFeatures=(appdata['mainFeatures'] as List?)?.map(
            (mainFeaturesdata)=>mainFeaturesdata['label']).toList,

                      benefits=(appdata['benefits'] as List?)?.map(
            (benefitsdata)=>benefitsdata['label']).toList,
                    ),).toList;
```

maybe try this code with whole jsondecode then extract toJson methods if it works..

Comment: where exactly you want me to add following because I model I already have that 
My issue is that from the main class Like items.name I get the result but correspondence to item.appdata don't get that because it's a list and I am showing data specific to a user so thinking that it would be easy to show specific data

Comment: if you want to show  appdetails list then you will need to use column/row or any widget that takes list of widgets to use it like `[...(appDetailsList.map((appdetails)=>yourwidget(appdetails)).toList)]` basically make list of widget from your appdetails list and use spread operator (...)